# Spring Boot & Theme Change

Tags: spring, spring-boot, themes

I'm using Spring Boot with Thymeleaf.
And I created sub tempalte folder for PC, Mobile, Tablet, like theme.
Now, I'd like to change the template folder by user.

[My Template Folder]
 - PC    : template/pc/index.html
 - Mible : template/mobile/index.html

But I could't intercept view resolver. 
How to use?

Answer (score 0):

just in java-configuration add

```
@Autowired
private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;
```

then just register your custom template resolver.

```
@PostConstruct
public void extension() {
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(dbTemplateResolver());
}
```